# Why nothing sending to google firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so I do not even know how to describe the problem, all I can say that when I press on "SUBMIT" button first-time empty data sending to google database but when I refresh the page the data send automatic (see the vid if you lost, https://imgur.com/a/D1ySswQ)

----------My Codes---------

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
let medicName = document.getElementById("medic-name").value;
let medicTime = document.getElementById("medic-time").value;
let notes = document.getElementById("notes").value;

 var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB444udd_UeONooSUbjOplVqrElpHv4Hgc",
    authDomain: "my-first-project-9a87e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-first-project-9a87e.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my-first-project-9a87e",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "15533904472",
    appId: "1:15533904472:web:b260608b9c15e8f3"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  let MedicalData = firebase.database().ref('Medical Data');

       document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var data = {
        name: name,
        MedicName: medicName,
        MedicTime: medicTime,
        Notes: notes
      }
    MedicalData.push(data);
  });
```

**SOLVED!**
so i not know what happened or even why this solved the problem but i changed this part of code
from

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var data = {
        name: name,
        MedicName: medicName,
        MedicTime: medicTime,
        Notes: notes
      }
    MedicalData.push(data);
  });
```

to

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var data = {
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    MedicName: document.getElementById("medic-name").value,
    MedicTime: document.getElementById("medic-time").value,
    Notes: document.getElementById("notes").value
  }
  MedicalData.push(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your code inside `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
//add code here
});
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

Currently, when you click `submit` the first time, the `DOM` is still not completely loaded and that's why you get empty string values.

Comment: its weird but i solved the problem (See the post) soo you know why its solved by this way ? im confused so i want to know why this way solved it